# writing dates with influxr_write to influxdb

Tags: r, influxdb

I am testing influxr for writing to influxdb from R:

https://github.com/influxr/influxr

The following example is taken from github readme and it works:

```
    # Load the influxr package
library(influxr)

# Define a client to hold connection parameters to your server running the influxDB database instance. Here you can also provide username and password if authentication is needed.

tss_client <- influxr_connection(host = 'localhost', ssl = FALSE)

# Test the connection
ping(tss_client)


# Generate random data with different data types
# Number of data points to generate
n = 1e5

# Create dummy data.frame for uploading
dummy_upload <-
  data.frame(
    time = Sys.time() + 1:n,
    Temp = round(rnorm(n) * 50, digits = 2),
    H = rnorm (n),
    DOY = floor(runif(n, 0, 365)),
    Code = replicate(n, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 4), collapse = ''))
  )


# Define meta data, knows as tags, for uploading to influxDB
tags <-
  c(
    station = 'New York',
    instrument = 'weather1'
  )


# Upload the data with the meta data
res <- influxr_write(
  x = dummy_upload,
  client = tss_client,
  measurement = 'test1',
  database = 'test',
  precision = 'ms',
  missing = c(NA, -9999),
  tags = tags,
  timestamp = 1, verbose = TRUE)
```

I have changed using a sequence of dates only:

```
n1 = 1e2

# Create dummy data.frame for uploading
dummy_upload <-
  data.frame(
    time = seq(as.Date('2015-09-15'), by = "1 days", length.out=n1),
    Temp = round(rnorm(n) * 50, digits = 2),
    H = rnorm (n),
    DOY = floor(runif(n, 0, 365)),
    Code = replicate(n, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 4), collapse = ''))
  )


head(dummy_upload)

# Define meta data, knows as tags, for uploading to influxDB
tags <-
  c(
    station = 'Houston',
    instrument = 'weather2'
  )


# Upload the data with the meta data
res <- influxr_write(
  x = dummy_upload,
  client = tss_client,
  measurement = 'test1',
  database = 'test',
  precision = 'ms',
  missing = c(NA, -9999),
  tags = tags,
  timestamp_format='%Y-%m-%d',
  timestamp = 1, 
  verbose = TRUE)
```

I am getting the following output:

[image]

and the following error:

> Error in format_timestamp(x, timestamp, timestamp_format, source_tz =
> tz,  :    Could not use provided timestamp.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The mantainer of this lovely packages replied to me by email and gives me several hints.
My code has some issues in the second part because it is still using n in some parts while it should use n1.
But the most important issue with my approach is that R treats dates with as.Date and time stamps differently. And since influxDB expects the time stamp to have a time component in it. A workaround would be to convert the date to POSIXct simply by using

```
as.POSIXct(seq(as.Date('2015-09-15'), by = "1 days", length.out=10))
```

I am here attaching a full version of my code:

```
# Load the influxr package
library(influxr)

# Define a client to hold connection parameters to your server running the influxDB database instance. Here you can also provide username and password if authentication is needed.

tss_client <- influxr_connection(host = 'localhost', ssl = FALSE)

# Test the connection
ping(tss_client)


# Generate random data with different data types
# Number of data points to generate
n = 1e5

# Create dummy data.frame for uploading
dummy_upload <-
  data.frame(
    time = Sys.time() + 1:n,
    Temp = round(rnorm(n) * 50, digits = 2),
    H = rnorm (n),
    DOY = floor(runif(n, 0, 365)),
    Code = replicate(n, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 4), collapse = ''))
  )


# Define meta data, knows as tags, for uploading to influxDB
tags <-
  c(
    station = 'New York',
    instrument = 'weather1'
  )


# Upload the data with the meta data
res <- influxr_write(
  x = dummy_upload,
  client = tss_client,
  measurement = 'test1',
  database = 'test',
  precision = 'ms',
  missing = c(NA, -9999),
  tags = tags,
  timestamp = 1, verbose = TRUE)


n1 = 1e2

# Create dummy data.frame for uploading
dummy_upload <-
  data.frame(
    time = as.POSIXct(seq(as.Date('2015-09-15'), by = "2 days", length.out=n1)),
    Temp = round(rnorm(n1) * 50, digits = 2),
    H = rnorm (n1),
    DOY = floor(runif(n1, 0, 365)),
    Code = replicate(n1, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 4), collapse = ''))
  )


head(dummy_upload)

# Define meta data, knows as tags, for uploading to influxDB
tags <-
  c(
    station = 'Houston',
    instrument = 'weather2'
  )


# Upload the data with the meta data
res <- influxr_write(
  x = dummy_upload,
  client = tss_client,
  measurement = 'test2',
  database = 'test',
  precision = 'ms',
  missing = c(NA, -9999),
  tags = tags,
  timestamp_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
  timestamp = 1, 
  verbose = TRUE)
```